# Why does my memory usage seem so off?

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory

I've recently started getting popup warnings on Windos 8 that I need to close programs to free memory. After a fresh reboot, I ran taskmanager just to see what my memory is doing and this is what I've got:

[image: taskmgr]

Now, my computer has 6GB of RAM, as shown here:

[image: properties]

Now, if I were indeed using 34% of my memory, shouldn't it be more in the 2GB range? Could something else be eating it up somewhere? I've had this computer for over a year and this is only just starting to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't look in the "Users" tab. Look in the "processes" tab, and make sure to view all processes by all users, and add up the memory used by all processes. That is how it gets the 34% total. You are just looking at the memory used by the processes started *by you*; in reality, the system runs many processes in the background as different users (SYSTEM, Local Service, Network Service, etc.) which will not show up if you are just looking at processes started by your user.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RAMMAp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) to see why you have a high RAM Usage.

[image]

MS explained [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx) and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-6-RAMMap) how to interpret the values.